# Problem compiling javafx project with maven on Vscode

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, javafx, compilation

I have a javafx project that I want to compile. Its source code is composed of two classes 'App.java' and 'Main.java' located in the same package name 'app'.

Main.java code:

```
package h4131.app;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        App.main(args);
    }
}
```

App.java code:

```
package h4131.app;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

import h4131.view.WindowBuilder;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        // WindowBuilder windowBuilder = new WindowBuilder(stage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Basically, when the Main.java class is compiled, it should calls the main function of the App class and should then produce an executable named 'agile.jar'.

But when compiling Main.java, I get the following error:

Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
App.main(args);
^
symbol:   variable App
location: class Main
1 error
error: compilation failed

It seems that it can't find the App.java class located in the same package and I don't understand why.

The tricky part is that I can launch the executable with a shell outside of Vscode with this command : java -jar agile.jar

So the problem might be with vscode.

I tried to delete and reinstall the JPK, Java, I changed the path variable to the right location, I restarted my computer, rebuilt the project in vscode but none of that seems to work.

Comment: Instructions on getting started with JavaFX are are [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/), including setups for VSCode and other IDEs.  Follow those instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command and rebuild:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace`

[image]